# Using async/await with form group

Tags: angular, asynchronous

So I am trying to make a form with the FormGroup in angular 8. I am calling an async method and awaiting on the api call that I am making. Even though I am going this it still seems to try to create the form before the data is there from the api call. Am I doing something in the wrong order?

Here is the controller:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../auth.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { CustomValidator } from './custom-validator';
import { FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'password-entry',
  templateUrl: './password-entry.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./password-entry.component.scss']
})
export class PasswordEntryComponent implements OnInit {

  resetPasswordForm: FormGroup;
  passwordComplexity: Subscription;
  complexity: any;
  validatorArray: Array<ValidatorFn> = [];
  token: String;

  errorMap: Object = {
    'Minimum of 8 characters long': 'hasEightCharacters',
    'Contains 1 lowercase letter': 'hasLowerCase',
    'Contains 1 uppercase letter': 'hasUpperCase',
    'Contains 1 number': 'hasNumber',
    'Contains 1 special character (!@#$%^&*)': 'hasSpecialCharacter',
  }

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.token = params.token;
    });
    this.setupResetForm();
  }

  private async setupResetForm() {
    await this.authService.getResetPasswordComplexity(this.token).subscribe(res => {
      this.complexity = res;
    });

    for (const c of this.complexity) { <--- this is undefined
      let errorObject: Object = {};
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.errorMap)) {
        if (key === c.description) { errorObject[value] = true }
      }
      this.validatorArray.push(CustomValidator.validateRegex(RegExp(c.test), errorObject));
    }

    this.resetPasswordForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      password: [
        null,
        Validators.compose([
          Validators.required,
          ...this.validatorArray
        ])
      ],
      confirmPassword: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    },
    { validator: CustomValidator.validatePasswordMatch });
  }

  sendResetPasswordRequest(): void {
    if (this.resetPasswordForm.valid) {
      let resetBody = {
        password: this.resetPasswordForm.value.password,
        token: this.token
      }
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.passwordComplexity.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: instead of forcing async / await, why not just do it all in the subscribe handler?

Comment: @bryan60 it still gives me `formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.` even if I move everything into that subscribe handler.

Comment: @bryan60 I was able to fix it by adding `*ngIf="resetPasswordForm"` to the HTML. WIsh I didnt have to do that but I guess it works then.

Comment: no matter what, you need to wait for your form to instantiate, if it needs to instantiate asynchronously, then that's just always going to be needed.

Comment: @bryan60 Okay if you could write an answer for me to accept that would be great!

Comment: wrote it up for you, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand Observable and async-await.

you need to call async function with await keyword

```
await this.setupResetForm();
```

And the following doesn't make sense, because Observable.subscribe is already asynchronous meaning `this.authService.getResetPasswordComplexity(this.token)` will call a service and when it gets a response(success or an error) it will then call the success method you pass as a callback to subscribe() method.

```
await this.authService.getResetPasswordComplexity(this.token).subscribe(res => {
  this.complexity = res;
});
```

for your use case you can simply put the whole section inside the subscribe section

```
private setupResetForm(newtoken:string) {
    this.authService.getResetPasswordComplexity(newtoken).subscribe(res => {
        for (const c of this.complexity) {
              let errorObject: Object = {};
              for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.errorMap)) {
                  if (key === c.description) { errorObject[value] = true }
              }
              this.validatorArray.push(CustomValidator.validateRegex(RegExp(c.test), errorObject));
        }

        this.resetPasswordForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          password: [
            null,
            Validators.compose([
              Validators.required,
                  ...this.validatorArray
            ])
          ],
          confirmPassword: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
        },
        { validator: CustomValidator.validatePasswordMatch });
    });
}
```

The same would be true for you `ngOnInit()`
Since your `setResetForm()` needs `this.token` which is getting from `this.route.queryParams.subscribe(...`. You need to call that from inside the subscribe method passing it the token. That way if you route query params changes it will call the `setResetForm()` again.

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    this.token = params.token;
    this.setupResetForm(this.token);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of forcing async / await, move your code into the subscribe handler:

```
  private setupResetForm() {
    this.authService.getResetPasswordComplexity(this.token).subscribe(res => {
      this.complexity = res;


      for (const c of this.complexity) { <--- this is undefined
        let errorObject: Object = {};
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.errorMap)) {
          if (key === c.description) { errorObject[value] = true }
        }
        this.validatorArray.push(CustomValidator.validateRegex(RegExp(c.test), errorObject));
      }

      this.resetPasswordForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        password: [
          null,
          Validators.compose([
            Validators.required,
            ...this.validatorArray
          ])
        ],
        confirmPassword: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
      },
      { validator: CustomValidator.validatePasswordMatch });
    });
  }
```

and add any needed *ngIf statements to ensure you wait till your form is instantiated